# Length Contraction

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, special-relativity

> At what speed does a meter stick move if its length is observed to
>   shrink to $0.5$ m?

What would we think for this question?  It doesn't seem too hard but couldn't work it out. That's why I want to take your thinkings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction)
$$
L=\frac{L_{0}}{\gamma(v)}=L_{0}\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}
$$
where
$L_0$ is the proper length (the length of the object in its rest frame),
$L$ is the length observed by an observer in relative motion with respect to the object,
$v$ is the relative velocity between the observer and the moving object,
$c$ is the speed of light.

So $L_0=1\mathrm{m}$, $L=0.5\mathrm{m}$ gives 
$$
v = \frac{\sqrt{3} c}{2}
$$